# Bootstrap Select DropDown not working correctly when appending record from AJAX success

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I'm using Bootstrap Select plugin for dropdown multi select and other things.
When I fetch record from database and append it to fills data inside dropdown (which I want) and also outside the dropdown

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
   <asp:Label runat="server"> Select Report's </asp:Label>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
   <select class="selectpicker ddlMulti" style="background-color:white"  multiple>
   </select>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "OssmWebService.asmx/FillDropdown",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('.ddlMulti').append("<option value='0'>--Select--</option>");
            $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
                $(".ddlMulti").append($("<option></option>").html(value.IntName));
            });
            debugger;
            $('.ddlMulti').selectpicker('refresh');
        }   
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function (data) {
      /*get response as json */
       $('#ddlMulti').find("option:eq(0)").html("Select ..");
      var obj=data;//alert(obj);
      $(obj).each(function()
      {
       var option = $('<option />');
       option.attr('value', this.value).text(this.label);           
       $('#ddlMulti').append(option);
     });  }
```

Use Id its better than class